# How do I prevent tar from overwriting an existing archive?

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I backup files a few times a day on Ubuntu/Linux with the command `tar -cpvzf ~/Backup/backup_file_name.tar.gz directory_to_backup/`, (the file name contains the date in YYYY-MM-DD format and a letter from a to z - a is the first backup for this date etc.) but I want to create a new archive, not overwrite the archive if it already exists. How do I prevent tar from overwriting an existing archive? If the archive exists, I want tar to exit without doing anything (and if possible, display an error message).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created the file `~/scripts/tar.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f $1 ]; then
    echo "Oops! backup file was already here."
    exit
fi
tar -cpvzf $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
```

Now I just have to type:

```
~/scripts/tar.sh ~/Backup/backup_file_name_`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_a.tar.gz directory_to_backup/
```

And the backup file is created if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @fedorqui did answer your question. You should have marked his response as the answer which you didn't even after you said you would.

Comment: @Gregg He doesn't understand how this works...

Answer (score 9):

Check the existence of the file beforehand:

```
if [ -f ~"/Backup/[backup_file_name].tar.gz" ]; then
    echo "ooops backup file was already here"
    exit
fi
tar -cpvzf ~/Backup/[backup_file_name].tar.gz directory_to_backup/
```

Note that the `~` has to be outside the double quotes if you want it to be expanded.

---

### Update

> Thanks. Do you know how to make the archive file name and directory to
>   backup as command line arguments? The file name includes the full
>   path.

You can use `$1`, `$2` and so on to indicate the parameters. For instance:

```
if [ -f $1 ]; then
    echo "ooops backup file was already here"
    exit
fi
tar -cpvzf $1 $2
```

And then call the script with:

```
./script.sh file backup_dir
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to make the archive file name and directory to backup as command line arguments? The file name includes the full path.

Comment: Why did you unaccept the answer? Didn't you use my answer to create your own project? Try to be grateful if you want to get help.

Comment: Your answer is not complete. Look at my answer below. If you change to $1 and $2 I can accept your answer.

Comment: My post was a complete answer of your initial post. I just updated for completeness sake, but make sure you know what you want to ask beforehand. If you keep adding requirements, most probably people won't feel like answering.

Comment: OK, thanks. I accepted your answer again. I also edited my original question, it would help if you answer my new question too - I want to check all files from a to z and create the first file that doesn't exist.

Comment: As this is a brand new thing, I recommend you to  [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This way you will get more people's attention, because the question will appear in the top of the list of questions.

Comment: I tried the script and works fine for me, but if the number of arguments is not determined, what is the best way? I want set arguments more flexible such as  `./script.sh file foo bar baz` or sometimes like `./script.sh file foo bar`

Comment: @RohanKishibe use `$@`, as described for example in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198954/40596).

Comment: @fedorqui `"$@"` is safer than just `$@`! Without the quotes, `$@` splits any argument cointaining spaces into multiple arguments.