# how to prevent overwrite existing files when using tar command

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I made a mistake that forgot to assign argument of the file name when using `tar` command like below:

```
[john@foobar foo]$ ll
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 0  7月  4 19:20 2018 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 0  7月  4 19:20 2018 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 0  7月  4 19:20 2018 file3
[john@foobar foo]$ tar -cvzf file1 file2 file3
file2
file3
[john@foobar foo]$ ll
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 130  7月  4 19:21 2018 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john   0  7月  4 19:20 2018 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john   0  7月  4 19:20 2018 file3
```

When forget to assign archive file name, `tar` overwrites and creates the archive `file1`.

I checked `man tar`, but it seems there is no option such as `cp` shows a prompt when same name file already exists.

To create a foolproof script is a possible way?

Answer (score 21):

From `man tar`:

```
-k, --keep-old-files
       don’t replace existing files when extracting, treat them as errors

--skip-old-files
       don’t replace existing files when extracting, silently skip over them
```

Comment: This option is for extracting. when creating an archive, this option doesn't work.

Comment: Ouch! Sorry, I understood you were talking about extracting files. In that case, you should check beforehand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680601/how-do-i-prevent-tar-from-overwriting-an-existing-archive